# Chromatic number for sets of five or more elements

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

> **Definition.** Given the set $D$ of positive integer numbers, we construct 
>   the 
>   *distance graph* for the integers, which vertices are $\Bbb{Z}$ and two numbers $x$ and $y$ are connected if 
>   the distance is an element of $D$, i.e. $|x-y|\in D$.
>
> We call $\chi(D)$ the chromatic number of the set $D$, defined as the minimum 
>   number of colors needed to colour the distance graph, such that two adjacent 
>   vertices does have different color.

I found that for two and three elements the problem of find the chromatic 
number 
was totally solved. See the paper *Chromatic number of distance graph 
generated by sets $\{2,3,x,y\}$*, of Daphne Der-Fen Liu and Aileen Sutedja.

In this paper, the authors solved the problem of finding the Chromatic number 
for 
the set $\{2,3,x,y\}$ (as the title say) for $x,y$ positive integer numbers. In 
the same paper they state Barajas and Serra's theorem:

> **Theorem.** Let $D$ is a set of four positive integers. Then $\chi(D)\leq 4$ 
>   unless $D=\{1,2,3,4m\}$ or $D=\{x,y,x+y,x-y\}$ where $x$ and $y$ are odd 
>   integers.

For the exeptions given in last theorem we have

> **Theorem (Liu and Zhu).** If $x$ and $y$ are positive odd integers, 
>   $\chi(\{x,y,x+y,x-y\})=5$. Also, $\chi(\{1,2,3,4m\})=5$.

The authors of the cited paper, ended the job of characterization of the 
chromatic number for sets of four elements.

The purpose of citing this paper and state the last theorems here is because I'm searching on this type of results for sets of five or more elements:

> **Q1:** For sets of five or more elements, What is the chromatic number?

For a special case we kown the result: if the given set consist of four or more 
primes, then $\chi(D)=4$ (Egleton, et. al. *Coluring prime distance graphs*, 
1990)

The authors cite a result, which gives upper and lower bound for this number:

> **Theorem (Zhu).** For any given distance set $D$, it holds that
>   $$\chi_f(D)\leq \chi(D)\leq \lceil 1/\kappa(D)\rceil,$$
>   where $\chi_f(D)$ is the fractional chromatic number and 
>   $$\kappa(D)=\sup\{\alpha\in(0,1/2)\mid \|td\|\geq \alpha\text{ for some }t\in 
> (0,1),\text{ for all }d\in D\}.$$

I'm interested in this kind of bounds for the chromatic number.

> **Q2:** How good are this bounds for the chromatic number? There are another 
>   bounds for this number?

In Math SE I found a result [The fractional chromatic number as a lower bound 
for the chromatic number for graph coloring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227174/the-fractional-chromatic-number-as-a-lower-bound-for-the-chromatic-number-for-gr), also, in Math OverFlow I found 
[Bounds on chromatic number of k-planar graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168440/bounds-on-chromatic-number-of-k-planar-graphs?rq=1). Actually the first one is 
included in Zhu's theorem (first inequality).

Any help or reference will be appreciate.